# Jenkins Job cancelled during the quiet period still builds

Tags: jenkins

I'm using the polling scm (git) plugin to trigger jobs.  I've set the quiet period to 30 seconds for a specific job.

When I commit:

- the job indeed sits in the "build queue" for 30 seconds.
- I cancel it, and it goes away
- However the polling scm plugin seems to re-trigger and then build the job.   at the next poll period

How do I cancel the job without letting it start, and then canceling it?

Comment: Not possible with polling triggered by timer, trigger the poll by post commit-hook, then it won't trigger until the next commit.

Comment: If you change this to an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Added, plus some explainations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with *timer* triggered scm polling.

The reason is, that on each poll jenkins will compare the remote to the local revision and will find out that the remote revision it is newer thus triggering a build. Aborting the build before a checkout or update doesnt change the local revision so it will retrigger a build on the next poll triggered by the timer.

A solution is, to make use of *post-commit hooks*.

Post-commit hooks are configured on the remote machine and are basically scripts that run after a commit has happened. As you can trigger a poll by calling some url on your jenkins server, its merely some configuration on the scm server to trigger a poll exactly after a commit has happened. That way, after an abort, jenkins will only trigger a poll on the next commit to the repository.

Theres usually some hints how to setup this in the documentation of the various scm plugins, i.e. the [git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository).